# How can I determine whether a day lies within the last week or not?

Tags: excel, vba

Given a date, how can I determine whether this day lies within the last week or not using vba?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract your input date/time from the current date/time, which you can get by calling `Now()` (parentheses optional in VBA).

```
input = DateValue("March 14, 2014")
difference = Now() - input
```

If the result is greater than 0 and less than 7, the input value is within the last week.
A value less than zero means that the input is in the future.